# How to calculate several slopes from linear regressions in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have measured the methane concentration in soil incubations (closed jars with soil in them) over time. To calculate the methane production rate I need to fit a second‐order polynomial regression model to the relationship between methane concentration (ch4_umol) and time (stamp). I would like to make two new columns to my dataset: The value of the regression line slope and the Rsquared value. I would like to calculate these two values for each "jar_camp".

Can anyone help with this? That would be awesome!

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie and I primarily work with tidyverse.

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(jar_camp = c("1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", 
"1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", 
"2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", 
"3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", 
"1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", 
"2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", 
"3_pf2.1"), jar = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    campaign = c("pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", 
    "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", 
    "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
    "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
    "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
    "pf2.1"), stamp = structure(c(1546688646, 1546688647, 1546688649, 
    1546688651, 1546688653, 1546688654, 1546689321, 1546689323, 
    1546689324, 1546689326, 1546689328, 1546689329, 1546689877, 
    1546689878, 1546689880, 1546689882, 1546689884, 1547031076, 
    1547031077, 1547031079, 1547031081, 1547031083, 1547031084, 
    1547032136, 1547032137, 1547032139, 1547032141, 1547032143, 
    1547032144, 1547033073, 1547033075, 1547033076, 1547033078, 
    1547033080), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ch4_umol = c(74.982885373, 74.315864696, 75.405874095, 73.876607177, 
    74.153176726, 74.429746275, 159.645704961, 159.661973758, 
    159.678242555, 159.694511352, 159.710780149, 159.75958654, 
    134.673101566, 135.779379762, 135.584154198, 135.600422995, 
    136.6578948, 455.542584797, 455.656466376, 455.998111113, 
    455.998111113, 455.623928782, 455.591391188, 461.838609236, 
    461.887415627, 461.985028409, 461.789802845, 461.627114875, 
    461.789802845, 441.356193813, 440.982011482, 441.20977464, 
    441.112161858, 441.112161858)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with tidyverse / `purrr`:

```
data <-structure(list(jar_camp = c("1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", 
                                   "1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "1_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", 
                                   "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "2_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", 
                                   "3_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", 
                                   "1_pf2.1", "1_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", 
                                   "2_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", 
                                   "3_pf2.1"), jar = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
                                                       3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                      campaign = c("pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", 
                                   "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", 
                                   "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
                                   "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
                                   "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", 
                                   "pf2.1"), stamp = structure(c(1546688646, 1546688647, 1546688649, 
                                                                 1546688651, 1546688653, 1546688654, 1546689321, 1546689323, 
                                                                 1546689324, 1546689326, 1546689328, 1546689329, 1546689877, 
                                                                 1546689878, 1546689880, 1546689882, 1546689884, 1547031076, 
                                                                 1547031077, 1547031079, 1547031081, 1547031083, 1547031084, 
                                                                 1547032136, 1547032137, 1547032139, 1547032141, 1547032143, 
                                                                 1547032144, 1547033073, 1547033075, 1547033076, 1547033078, 
                                                                 1547033080), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                      ch4_umol = c(74.982885373, 74.315864696, 75.405874095, 73.876607177, 
                                   74.153176726, 74.429746275, 159.645704961, 159.661973758, 
                                   159.678242555, 159.694511352, 159.710780149, 159.75958654, 
                                   134.673101566, 135.779379762, 135.584154198, 135.600422995, 
                                   136.6578948, 455.542584797, 455.656466376, 455.998111113, 
                                   455.998111113, 455.623928782, 455.591391188, 461.838609236, 
                                   461.887415627, 461.985028409, 461.789802845, 461.627114875, 
                                   461.789802845, 441.356193813, 440.982011482, 441.20977464, 
                                   441.112161858, 441.112161858)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                             "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -34L))
library(tidyverse)
data <- data %>% group_by(campaign,jar_camp) %>% summarize(ch4_umol,dt=as.numeric(difftime(stamp,min(stamp)))) %>% ungroup()

calclm <- function(data) {
  campaign = data$campaign[[1]]
  lm <-lm(formula = ch4_umol ~ dt , data = data)
  lm.summary = summary(lm)
  list(campaign = campaign,intercept=lm$coefficients[[1]],slope=lm$coefficients[[2]] ,r.squared = lm.summary$r.squared)
}


res <- data %>% split(.$jar_camp) %>% map(~calclm(.x)) %>% bind_rows(.id="jar_camp")
res

jar_camp campaign intercept    slope r.squared
  <chr>    <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1_pf1.1  pf1.1         74.9 -0.0813   0.215   
2 1_pf2.1  pf2.1        456.   0.00188  0.000854
3 2_pf1.1  pf1.1        160.   0.0126   0.906   
4 2_pf2.1  pf2.1        462.  -0.0225   0.371   
5 3_pf1.1  pf1.1        135.   0.201    0.665   
6 3_pf2.1  pf2.1        441.  -0.0235   0.209
```

I converted `stamp` to seconds from begin of group (`dt`) so that the regression works properly.

Comment: `lm.summary$coefficients` contains the estimate, standard error, t-value, and p-value of each coefficient. If you just want to extract coefficients, `lm$coefficients` is ok.

Comment: Thanks @Darren Tsai, I simplified this part.

Comment: Thanks a lot Waldi. The code works brilliantly! I actually would very much like to see your solution with lm.summary$coefficients since I could use that information as well.

Comment: @Magnus, I included the summary in the results

Comment: Thanks Waldi, I was however actually interested in the the original code you made with lm.summary$coefficients. I did try myself, which I have added to my original question. However I do not get the slope values. Also, I am actually a bit in doubt, which of the coeffients that is the slope. "Intercept" would be the intercept with the y-axis, I guess, but is dt or dt2 the slope value I am looking for?

Comment: @Magnus, if you output for example the first result : `res[[1]]$summary$coefficients`, you get 3 coefs, intercept to the y axis, coef1 for dt, coef2 for dt2 = dt^2, which gives a quadratic regression as I understood your question : intercept + coef1 * dt1 + coef2 * dt^2. slope of a quadratic model is the derivative : coef1 + 2 * coef2 * dt. Are you looking for a quadratic regression or a linear regression?

Comment: r.squared is also available in the result, for example for the first regression : `res[[1]]$summary$r.squared`

Comment: Oh okay, I am looking for the coefficients from a linear regression - sorry if I was unclear in my question. I guess that means I should use dt and not dt2.

Comment: I do have some problems converting the list created into a dataframe however. Do you know how that is easily done? I would like a table with coefficients, r.squared etc as columns and the jar_camp column as rows.

Comment: @Magnus look into [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) package.

Comment: That looks great. However, I need a column in the table that identifies what the slope value is refering to. E.g. an extra column in the table with the jar_camp values.

Comment: Thanks again @Waldi! How would I do if also wanted to include "campaign" in the table

Comment: @Magnus, if last edit worked, would you mind accepting it so that others know the answer is useful?

Comment: @Waldi. Yes, sorry didn't know I had to do that. Again, thanks a million for all your help!