# Dynamic variables in functions in R for-loops

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to automate much of the linear regression/model selection workflow. But I ran into some problems with the for loops; I surmise they're mostly issues with the dynamic variable naming.

I managed to automate the loop for the first step (regression modelling). Though ideally I would like the model to be stored in the following convention: lm.model, lm**1**.model, lm**2**.model ... but I'm not sure how to place the dynamic number within the variable string. I only managed to place it at the end:

```
lm.model[i] <- for (i in 1:5){ 
              model_name <- paste("lm.model", i , sep = "")
              assign(model_name, lm(Y ~ poly(X, i), data = training.dat))
}
```

But going by the current labelling convention, the next step does not work:

```
lmod.fit[i] <- for(i in 1:5){
  fit_name <- paste("lmod.fit", i, sep = "")
  assign(fit_name, predict(lm.model[i], newdata = training.dat))
}
```

It returns the error

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict'
applied to an object of class "list"
```

In subsequent steps, I would also want to loop the pasting of the following parts:

```
x1 = lm.fit, 
x2 = lm2.fit,
x3 = lm3.fit,
x4 = lm4.fit,
x5 = lm5.fit
```

```
c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")
```

But I am having trouble with just using the paste() function as the output is a single character string.

If there is a less cumbersome way to do all this, please let me know what else I can try!

Comment: perhaps this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63072424/13513328) is relevant.

Comment: it's because the name is `lm.model1`, `lm.model2` not a vector or a list `lm.model`

Comment: you can check by running the `ls()` command that'll show you the objects that are in the .globalEnv

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be reorganized.  The assignment to `lm.model[i]` needs to be inside the loop, not outside:

```
lm.model <- list()
for (i in 1:5){ 
   model_name <- paste("lm.model", i , sep = "")
   lm.model[[model_name]] <- lm(Y ~ poly(X, i), data = training.dat)
}
```

The same for the predictions:

```
lmod.fit <- list()
for(i in 1:5){
  model_name <- paste("lm.model", i , sep = "")
  fit_name <- paste("lmod.fit", i, sep = "")
  lmod.fit[[fit_name]] <- predict(lm.model[[model_name]], newdata = training.dat)
}
```

I don't understand what your last request is about.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do those operations in the same `for` loop. Also the inverse function for `assign` is `get`. And `paste0` is faster than `paste(..., sep='')` and does the same.
You can use `ls()` to see the objects that exist in the global Environment

```
for (i in 1:5){ 
     #model_name == 'lm1.model'
     model_name <- paste0("lm", i,".model")
     assign(model_name, lm(Y ~ poly(X, i), data = training.dat))
     #fit_name == 'lmod1.fit'
     fit_name <- paste0("lmod", i,".fit")
     # if you want to have two loops then instead of model_name use paste0('lm',i,'.model') or sub('lmod(\\d+)\.fit', 'lm\\1.model', fit_name)
     assign(fit_name, predict(get(model_name), newdata = training.dat))
}
```